# Is there a simple solution to internal wifi access?

Tags: networking, router

I'm sure many people have the same issue.  Can this be solved easily with standard routers.

We have a standard network with lots of PCs, switches and routers.  Its a standard PC network with a simple server and 10 PCs.

We are a cookery school and have day students, we would like to be able to give these students wifi access from various parts of the school.  Can I set all routers up to only see the internet and the internet gateway and have no access to the internal network.

Do I need a special router?
I don't really want to have to run a seperate set of lines?

Can I achieve this with subnetmasks or something?

Comment: It's very likely possible to solve this with relatively small investments on your side but how exactly depends on your *exact* setup (network topology, models of switches and routers, floor plan etc.). Your question makes it clear though that you have a very limited amount of networking knowledge, so I would recommend to hire someone to do this for you.

Comment: Surely its possible to talk in the abstract about what kinds of things are possible, we have some good dlink routers, but most of the wifi hotspots are home/office type routers.  I don't mind spending money on decent routers, but I need to know in the abstract that it is possible over a single network.

Comment: @TobyAllen - go here: http://meraki.cisco.com/freeap - get something like that...works great, easy to administer, etc.  I don't work for them, just use them.  Aside from all of that, sure you can usually give what is called "guest access/hotel access" to users but you'll need to see if your DLink's can even offer that.  Or you can setup ACLs/rules/routing to only allow the wireless clients access out to the internet, sure.  You just need to know HOW to do it properly on your equipment.  That's why I mention the Meraki's since they are dead easy to do this.

Comment: It's not possible with the average home/soho switches and/or wireless routers. Perfectly possible with professional level gear - you can put the switch ports for the wireless routers on a separate vlan, if your switches can support that, for example. To give a more detailed answer we'd need to know more about your topology. For a start, is it a 'standard network with lots of PCs, switches and routers, or it a 'standard PC network with a simple server and 10 PCs'? It can't be both...

Comment: ... Unless you have 10 PCs that are widely geographically dispersed and therefore need 'lots of switches and routers' in order to connect them to one another and the server, at which point its not simple.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, the answer by @cia gives me something to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do what you want with what you have, but it won't be pretty.  By pretty, I mean, it will work, but it won't have flexibility or scalability, which may or may not be what you're after.

When working with wireless access, there are a few major points of contention:

1) Availability - ease of access, readiness of access

2) Flexibility - ease of change

3) Scalability - easy of expansion

and of course

4) Security

**Home Wireless Router - Independent Access Points**

[image: Example1]

If all you're looking for is availability, then using home-quality routers should be sufficient. e.g. [Cheap Wireless Router](http://store.linksys.com/Routers/Linksys-EA2700-DualBand-N600-Router-With-Gigabit_stcVVproductId145330223VVcatId551966VVviewprod.htm)

**Equipment** - Home wireless routers

**The Benefit** - very easy to set up.

**The Problem** - each router will have it's own network and it will be very difficult to get them talking with other network devices if you need them to (printing, internal computer-to-computer communications).  Ontop of that, each wireless router will need it's own UNIQUE SSID, so as to not conflict with the other router's wireless broadcasts.  This leads to other problems, such as access key management and mobility/access issues in some cases where someone's trying to stay connected while moving from one location to another crossing more than one wireless range and the system can't decide which SSID to stay connected to. And this doesn't cover whether or not you can separate your business/IT related network traffic from public access traffic, which can lead to other security issues.

**Access Points - Bridged Wireless Access Points**

[image: Example2]

If you want to add flexibility and scalability, you can use Wireless Access Points.  These are available in both the business or consumer grades.

**Equipment** - Wireless access points, and possibly a wireless access controller (for ease of management) e.g. [ZyXEL NWA3000](http://www.zyxel.com/uk/en/products_services/nwa3000_series.shtml?t=p)

**The Benefit** - easy to set up, but will require some basic networking knowledge.  This resolves many of the issues of the previous solution, allowing users to move and migrate from access point to access point fluidly. Centralized management.

**The Problem** - Security.  All access points will share the same access key.  This is still easier to manage than the home wireless router solution, but it's still a pain to have to manage these.  It does not completely resolve the separation of public network traffic from business/IT network traffic; but can be managed by other internal resources (layer 2 or 3 switch with VLAN management)

**Wireless HotSpot - Bridged Wireless Access Points with Registration/Access Management**

[image: Example3]

If you want the whole package, with all the bells and whistles, this is the path you want to take.

**Equipment** - A network admission control server/gateway, compatible wireless access points e.g. [Cisco NAC Guest Server](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10160/)

**The Benefit** - works just like hotel wireless access, depending on how it's set up; can allow users to register their own equipment, get separated into a VLAN for guest users to protect business/IT network traffic, can allow users limited access to local resources, no need for access key management (unless you want to), flexible, scalable, and offers monitoring, centralized management, and more depending on the final solution

**The Problem** - requires high level of network knowledge and can get pretty expensive

Comment: Thanks, I think the solution with each wifi having its own network is ideal, all i want is for people to see the internet and at the moment all our hotspots have seperate SSIDs so that's not a problem.  Thanks for your help.